# Windows 10 installation on SSHD failed

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, partitioning

I am currently trying to install Windows 10 on my new SSHD Seagate 4 TB and I am failing badly.

At first Windows 10 could not install. It hung while copying files to the SSHD. In the overview menu I had only 1 partition.

The error message I received was: **"The computer could not be setup for the next startup during installation process. Please restart installation to install Windows correctly."** This happened a few times...

Then I reset the partition table to MS DOS which was obviously a very big mistake. Because this split the flash memory and the HDD. I reversed that step by using the GPT table and am back to square 1 because now the same error occurs during the Windows 10 installation process.

The official Seagate website says nothing about required drivers to run it. I have no idea how to go on and really hope you guys can help me somehow.